How do i make a discord.js command option string be .toLowerCase()
I used to have a line of code that would listen for a answer in a command option and it included .toLowerCase() but now it doesnt work and just makes my bot crash here is the old code
 if (interaction.options.getString("favourite-pet").toLowerCase() === "dog") {
   
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle("No way dogs my fav too")
      .setDescription(" i cant believe we both love dogs")
      .setColor("Orange");

    interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] })
}

But now including the .toLowerCase() returns this in the terminal:
node:events:496
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toLowerCase')
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\Gababes bot\src\index.js:189:49)
    at Client.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (D:\Gababes bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (D:\Gababes bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (D:\Gababes bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:355:31)
    at WebSocketManager.<anonymous> (D:\Gababes bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:239:12)
    at WebSocketManager.emit (D:\Gababes bot\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.cjs:282:31)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (D:\Gababes bot\node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:1173:51)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (D:\Gababes bot\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.cjs:282:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\Gababes bot\node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:988:14)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:401:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)


Are you sure that interaction.options.getString("favourite-pet") returns something other than null?

yes beacuse when i get rid off the .tolowercase() it the command works fine

Do console.log(interaction.options.getString("favourite-pet")) to make sure.

You can use Optional Chaining to help resolve this error. interaction?.options?.getString("favourite-pet")?.toLowerCase().

The error you are encountering is due to attempting to call .toLowerCase() on a null value. This happens when interaction.options.getString("favourite-pet") returns null because the option "favourite-pet" was not provided.
To prevent this, you should add a check to ensure the value is not null before calling .toLowerCase().
Bellow I will provide a code snippet that should resolve this issue.
const favouritePet = interaction.options.getString("favourite-pet");

if (favouritePet && favouritePet.toLowerCase() === "dog") {
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("No way, dogs are my favorite too!")
        .setDescription("I can't believe we both love dogs!")
        .setColor("Orange");

    interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
} else {
    // Handle other cases or provide feedback if the option was not given
    interaction.reply({ content: "Please specify your favourite pet!" });
}

